# How can I rename (or even remove?) buddypress' wire-section?

Tags: wordpress, function, rename, buddypress

I am currently setting up an online community for the first time. I am a frequent worpress user, yet this one problem occurs:

I don't like the section name "wire". I'd much rather use something like "guestbook" or "short note" for it, but I cannot find the place to change it in the backend. It is not in the theme's CSS editor.

Same goes for the titles "Blog" of the Blog page or "Group/member listings" on the group/member pages :-(

Right now I am using
Wordpress MU 2.9.1.1
Buddy Press latest version
The free "Cosmic Buddy" Theme
I do have the "Enable Theme and Plugin Editor" and I could change the navbar button names with it and many other things, but not buddypress specific functions titles.

Answer (score 1):

i would think you could do it following [*Customizing Labels, Messages, and URLs*](http://codex.buddypress.org/how-to-guides/customizing-labels-messages-and-urls/) in BuddyPress' [*How-To Guides*](http://codex.buddypress.org/how-to-guides/).